# Calculations displaying 2 Currencies in WooCommerce Cart prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

```
Rp 500000 (USD $ 37.49)
```

I want to show two currency looks like above in Cart Totals in woocommerce (subtotal, shipping, discount, insurance[custom fee], packing fee[custom fee]).

I succed make it on subtotal, shipping, discount with adding below filter.

But that doesn't work on the two custom fee (insurance, packing fee). When I add $price_us to the .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount class, the insurance/packing fee amount will going wrong. If I did not add $price_us to the .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount class everything will be ok, but with only 1 currency.

```
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $decimals, 
  $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
  $price_us_int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $price), 10);
  $price_us_int = convert_idr_to_usd_cart($price_us_int);

  $price_us = "USD $ $price_us_int";

  return '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price .' ( '.$price_us.' )</span>';
}
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 20, 5 );
```

Is there anybody could help me with this situation.

Comment: You mean to say cart total should be shown in Indian and USA price format with accurate calculation dollar and rupees?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj yes, that's right Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update**

There is 2 main problems:

1) You are using the wrong hook. Instead you should use **`wc_price`**.

2) In your code and it's because you should directly use the unformatted **`$price`** argument available without using this:

```
$price_us_int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $price), 10);
```

Now as I don't have the code of your custom function **`convert_idr_to_usd_cart()`** I don't now how you make your calculation and how you set the number of decimals or this converted custom price.

So I have use this **for testing purpose**:

```
// Just for testing
function convert_idr_to_usd_cart( $price ){
    $convertion_rate = 0.016;
    $new_price = $price * $convertion_rate;
    return number_format($new_price, 2, '.', '');
}
```

**Here is the correct functional code** *(without this issues)*:

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $args ) {

    // The currency conversion custom calculation function
    $price_usd = convert_idr_to_usd_cart($price);

    // the currency symbol for US dollars
    $currency = 'USD';
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency );
    $price_usd = $currency_symbol.$price_usd; // adding currency symbol

    // The USD formatted price
    $formatted_price_usd = "<span class='price-usd'> (USD $price_usd)</span>";

    // Return both formatted currencies
    return $formatted_price . $formatted_price_usd;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: The problem still the same.  Actually when I remove `( '.$price_us.' ) from <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price .' </span>`, the `$price_us_int` variable show right value : `float(1.5) Rp20,000`.  But when I include `( '.$price_us.' )` code on the `<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price .' </span>` suddenly the `$price_us_int` variable will show wrong value.

Comment: @dipa Updated again my code with explanations … The problem was also the hook used. I have change it and change the code too. **Everything is OK** now. try it please. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for taking time helping me with this situation. It's still doesn't work on my custom fee (insurance and packing). When I include $formatted_price_usd on the return statement, wrong price value will appear, both in local and USD Rp42,949,673 (USD $3224.93). But when i remove $formatted_price_usd on the return statement the local price will show the right value Rp20,000 offcourse with no USD value.

Comment: It's works now, the problem is on my add custom fee filter. I Used `$subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();` to get the subtotal value before. It gave wrong value. I changed it to `$cart = $woocommerce->cart; $cart =  (array) $cart; $subtotal = $cart['subtotal'];` and everything going just fine now. Thank you very much Loic for helping me to correct my code.